# How Do I Modify My Code to be Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below, I have written a function that takes an array and a key to search and count the number of times the key matches an element in an array. I am attempting to modify my function to count the number of matches asynchronously but don't know how to best go about it. Any insight or examples would be greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
function countMatches(arr, key) 
{ 
    var count=0; 
    var i; 
    for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    { 
        if(arr[i] == key) count=count+1; 
    } 
    return count; 
}

let arr1 = [3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 6, 8, 9];
console.log(countMatches(arr1, 6));
```

Comment: Please check ``Promise`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: there's an npm package that let you use async in node, check out [https://www.npmjs.com/package/async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

Comment: What objective are you trying to achieve by making it async?

Comment: @jsejcksn I am just trying to familiarize myself with asynchronous execution as I have never learned when it is appropriate to use them. I was struggling because I was trying to use old style callbacks to no avail. Didn't know about promises.

Comment: @RyanHarding Ok, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70313156/438273) for the simplest modern syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
function countMatches(arr, key) 
{ 
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var count=0; 
        var i; 
        for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        { 
            if(arr[i] == key) count=count+1; 
        } 
        resolve(count); 
    });
}

let arr1 = [3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 6, 8, 9];
countMatches(arr1, 6).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: why not just add. `async` in the function definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a promise from any synchronous function by converting it to an [asynchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) using the `async` keyword:

```js
/** This is a sync function */
function getNumber1 () {
  return 42;
}

const n1 = getNumber1();
console.log({sync: n1}); // 42

/**
This is an async function
Notice the `async` keyword before `function`
It automatically returns a promise which resolves to the value
vvvvv                                                       */
async function getNumber2 () {
  return 42;
}

getNumber2().then(n2 => console.log({async: n2})); // 42
```

Answer (score 0):

async/ await

```
async function  countMatchesAsync(arr, key) 
{ 
    var count=0; 
    var i; 
    for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    { 
        if(arr[i] == key) count=count+1; 
    } 
    return await count; 
}

let arr1 = [3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 6, 8, 9];
countMatchesAsync(arr1, 6).then(console.log);
```